# Grouping Jasper Report horizontally

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a fairly straightforward Jasper Report that uses Grouping for up to 8 groups.  When I run it, it correctly groups and prints, but each group is on a new page.  Although there are several SO and other questions that ask this same thing, I have not been able to get this to work.

What I want is exactly what I have now, but instead, for each group to lay out horizontally on the page.

The report property "print order", which several people allude to, is not changing this behavior.  And when I tried setting "columns" to 3, it simply takes the first group and spreads its data over 3 columns, and then starts the next group on a new page.

I have tried every other combination of parameters that might prevent this, but without success.  Does anyone know if I can show the groups horizontally across the page?

Comment: Can you take a screen shot of your template and post it? And post your JRXML.

Comment: If i am reading your question right you want something like Excel Pivot Table?  If so Jasper calls them CrossTab (see Chapeter 15 of the Ireport Ultimate guide [link]http://community.jaspersoft.com/modal_forms/nojs/jf-user-login-register?destination=http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/ireport-ultimate-guide